# not executable: bin/rails using whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I am using whenever gem to run my model method(cron job)

My steps to install `whenever gem` is

Gemfile

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

In project path type

```
wheneverize .
```

In schedule.rb

```
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}
every 1.minute do
  runner 'Invoice.mark_as_overdue'
end
```

And when I check cron_log.log file its showing error

```
bundler: not executable: bin/rails
```

Any suggestion will be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Rufus-Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) gem, its easier to implement scheduling in Ruby